# Backup of an in-memory SQLiteDatabase to a file

Tags: android, sqlite

I currently have an in-memory [`SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) created using `SQLiteDatabase.create(null)`.  At a later point in time, I wish to backup this database to a file.

This is [well-documented](https://www.sqlite.org/backup.html) for the C SQLite API.  Essentially, I would like to reproduce the functionality of the `loadOrSaveDb` function, but it doesn't seem that the `sqlite3_backup` functions are available in the Android SQLite API.

If this is not directly possible through an equivalent to the C backup APIs, is there a straightforward way to comprehensively copy the contents of an in-memory SQLiteDatabase to a file-based one?

(This is essentially the same question as [Backup and restore sqlite from disk to memory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548026/backup-and-restore-sqlite-from-disk-to-memory-in-java), but with Android SQLite rather than JDBC.)

Comment: It does seem that Android is lacking in several standard SQLite functionalities. If your db is simple enough, though, you could just create a new on-disk db, and "manually" copy the in-memory db to it with SELECTs and INSERTs.

Comment: Unfortunately the structure and content of the database are user defined.

Comment: Still possible. Not fun or easy, but possible. Might be what you have to fall back on, given Android's SQLite limitations.

Comment: I'm leaning towards using a temporary file-backed database instead of a memory database.  This is for a direct port of a C++ codebase in which a memory database is used, but it might be the only reasonable compromise.