# how to send inmemory sqlite to filesystem in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i have created a database in sq-lite in-memory for my android app ,i want to push the in-memory database to file system. please help me out .

Tried looking for multiple places but could not find any solution.

Comment: See [Backup of an in-memory SQLiteDatabase to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943968/backup-of-an-in-memory-sqlitedatabase-to-a-file).

Comment: in the above link i am not getting any code to do it.

Comment: @NitheshBafna Could you explain where File System is on the android device on a hard drive on your PC also are you talking about using adb commands Look up adb if you are not sure what that is

Comment: @Grendel -- File system like Fash or ROM. basically i want to push the data from RAM to ROM.

Comment: @NitheshBafna Out of my pay grade and scope of practice But how do you put data in in RAM or where is it if it is in RAM Is that like memory cash